Number of elements of a subgroup is a divisor of the number of elements in the group
I just came across this statement in an informal context - in this YouTube video on a group theory exercise
Is it a provable theorem? Appreciate any inputs/links to read further.

Have you tried to prove it? It is easy.

@ahron This result is called Lagrange's theorem. As a hint towards the usual proof, you can show $|G|/|H|$ is the number of cosets that $H$ has within $G$. Since $|G/|H|$ counts something, it is necessarily a whole number.

@Malady I don't really agree with you that the proof is easy. It's only easy if you know how to do it.

@DerekHolt You are right, I suppose. It is easy if one has been introduced to the idea of cosets, which is usually where this exercise is presented in a text.

@ahron After you read Nicky Hekster’s answer, you should try to prove it and add your attempt into the question, to avoid it getting closed.

One can avoid cosets, see here for example, but I don't think one should avoid it. Anyway, the basics of group theory will be useful for any such question.

Please try to make your posts self-contained (e.g., by typing up the statement of the theorem).

Probably you do not know what a coset is: it is an equivalence class of the equivalence relation on the set (group) $G$ and subgroup $H$, defined by $x \sim y$ if and only if $xH=yH$, where $gH:=\{gh : h\in H \}$. Prove that this is an equivalence relation indeed and consider the equivalence classes. Show that the size of each of the equivalence classes is $|H|$.
The equivalence classes are called left cosets (because we multiply $H$ on the left. Similarly, there are right cosets, which, by the way do not need to be equal to the left ones (can you think of an example?). However, the number of right and left cosets is always the same, try to prove it! And this number is $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$, which is called the index of $H$ in $G$. Also written as $|G:H|$. Apart from finite groups, it can also be defined for infinite groups with infinite cardinal numbers.
And, finally, for a question that Lagrange missed ... see here.

Please refrain from answering PSQs.

Sure just helping
